# How to open a specific Bootstrap tab located on a modal by URL?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to open a specific tab in a modal by URL. To open the modal I added following JavaScript to the end of the website. By entering website.com/#modal-6 it opens the website with modal-6 activated.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#modal-6") > -1) {
        var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modal-6'));
        myModal.show();
    }
});
```

This modal contains a several tabs. How can I achieve that the tab with id=tab-13 is shown, when loading the website through website.com/#modal-6?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<ul id="tabContainer-11" class="nav nav-tabs tabcontainer mb-3" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button id="tab-12" class="nav-link" data-bs-target="#tab-content-12" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-12" aria-selected="false"> Login </button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button id="tab-13" class="nav-link active" data-bs-target="#tab-content-13" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-content-13" aria-selected="true"> ...or subscribe now! </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome! Thanks for pointing me there!

So the code is:

```
 // show modal with id=modal-6, if url contains "#modal-6"
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

   if (window.location.href.indexOf("#modal-6") > -1) {

     var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('modal-6'));
     //var myTab = new bootstrap.Tab(document.getElementById('tab-13'));
     myModal.show();

     //open tab with id=tab-13, when modal is shown
     var myModalEl = document.getElementById('modal-6')
     myModalEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
       // do something...
       var myTab = document.querySelector('#tab-13');
       var tab = new bootstrap.Tab(myTab);

       tab.show();
     });

   }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd leverage the modal event `shown.bs.modal` to call the function to show your tab, using `tab.show()`. See docs for [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events) and [tab methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#show).